# Quitting a job after signing the contract in Germany

Tags: germany, employment, contracts

I have completed my Master's in Germany. I have got an offer from a company, which I should accept within 5 days. There is positive feedback from another company, but no offer has been made yet and it is unlikely that one will be made within 5 days time.

The contract I have now says that there will be a probation period of 6 months and if I decide to quit in the first month of joining, the notice period is only 2 weeks.

I would like to sign the contract and accept the offer. However, is there a possibility to quit without having personally gone to the office on the first working day? The contract does not explicity state what happens if I am a no-show.

More importantly, does this 2 week notice period commence from the date of entry or from the date of signing the contract?

Just further information, the starting date mentioned in the received contract is two months from the date of signing the contract.

If it matters, the job applicant is a non-EU citizen.

Comment: Don't do that. If you sign a contract that says you start on day X, then that means you need to show up on that day - it's legally binding. Even if you were to resign, you'd still have to work your notice period (unless they give you gardening leave). Careful about references - in Germany, they will know your work history (even if it's for a couple of days), and they will probably not provide a good reference.

Comment: @rbm That's on aspect of the question, though, if you are supposed to start work in a month from now and your notice period is two weeks, you have ample time to give notice without ever showing to work, while doing everything by the book. Or does that work differently in Germany? (The usual caveat about people gossiping and professional reputation apply but I don't think you would need an actual certificate for a place where you never really worked).

Comment: Just edited the question to add the detail that there is a solid two months time between the date of signing the contract and the start date.